# list_editable is super slow on save

Tags: django, django-admin

I've added a model to the Django admin and I have enabled list_editable for a specific field. When I save the changes, it takes a lot of times and at some point the request timeout.

Here the model:

```
class ClientASTM(models.Model):
    client = ForeignKey2(Client, related_name='astms', verbose_name='client')
    day = models.DateField(verbose_name='day')
    last_occurence_date = models.DateField(verbose_name='last occurence', null=True, blank=True)
    search_term = models.CharField(verbose_name='search term', max_length=255)
    is_exclude = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='is exclude', default=False)

    add_datetime = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='add datetime', auto_now_add=True)
    mod_datetime = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='mod datetime', auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s: %s -> %s' % (self.client, self.search_term, self.day)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-day',)
        unique_together = (('client', 'day', 'search_term'),)
        verbose_name = 'Client ASTM'
```

And here my model admin:

```
class ClientASTMAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_editable = (
        'is_exclude',
    )

    list_display = (
        'id',
        'day',
        'search_term',
        'is_exclude'
    )
```

It is pretty basic and I do not know what it takes so much time.

Do you have any ideas where I could investigate ? Or do you know what I did wrong ?

Thank you a lot for your help.

Comment: what is ForeignKey2

Comment: It's a django package (django-select2-forms). It inherit from models.ForeignKey

Comment: MOst of these django add ons are hugelly over rated. This one was last updated 3 years back.

Comment: Why don't you enable django debug toolbar and see what queries are executed? or enabled query logging in settings.py

Comment: Yes, I aware of the plugin. I am not a bug fan myself but it was already there and the project is pretty huge. So, it would take me a lot of time to remove it. Regarding your other comment, I tried debug toolbar and django logging with DEBUG level, not much of a success. Anyway, I have updated my origin post since I have found an alternate solution.

Comment: you should rollback your edit and post that as an update instead. Then you can accept it as the correct answer. What you are saying about list editable is in fact correct but usually you only get at most a 100 items on the page depending on your settings.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up replacing list_editable by an admin action. My theory is that when you use "list_editable", it parses every single object. So, if you have 1,000,000 items, it will parse every one of them.

Here is my solution:

```
class ClientASTMAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    actions = ('exclude_keyword', )

    list_display = (
        'id',
        'day',
        'search_term',
        'is_exclude',
    )

    def exclude_keyword(self, request, queryset):
        for instance in queryset:
            instance.is_exclude = not instance.is_exclude
            instance.save()
    exclude_keyword.short_description = 'Exclude (or include) keywords'
```

It's faster because it only update the selected items.